# substitute only some numbers by their decrement

Tags: python, regex

I have this string: a9*a9 + a10*a10 
and I would like to have: a9*a8 + a10*a9

I think re.sub() from Python should be useful, but I am not familiar with group() that I've seen in some examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your string always have aN*aN like a9*a9 or it can have a9*a9*a9 format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's another solution method:

```
import re

s = 'a9*a9 + a10*a10 + a8*a8 + a255*a255 + b58*b58 + c58*c58'
string = re.sub('[ ]', '', s)  # removed whitespace from string (optional:only if you are not sure how many space you can get in string)
x = string.split('+')
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-z])([\d]+)')
ans = ''
for element in x:
    for letter, num in re.findall(pattern, element):
        st = ''
        for i in range(len(element.split('*'))):
            st = st + '*' + (letter+str(int(num)-i))
            # print(str(letter) + str(int(num)-i))
    ans = ans + '+' + st[1:]
print(ans[1:])
```

Output :

```
a9*a8+a10*a9+a8*a7+a255*a254+b58*b57+c58*c57
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure of the input is `a\d*a\d + a\d*a\d + ...` you can use a callback in the `re.sub` function:

```
import re


def decrement(match):
    if match.group(1) != match.group(2):
        return match.group(0)

    return 'a{}*a{}'.format(match.group(1), str(int(match.group(2)) - 1))


re.sub(r'a(\d)\*a(\d)', decrement, 'a3*a3 + a5*a5 + a3*a7')
# a3*a2 + a5*a4 + a3*a7
```

Comment: `r'a(\d+)\*a(\d+)'` for multidigit numbers